# Bypassing the SSL error in Webview control windows 8.1 app or webbrowser control

Tags: windows, webview, windows-phone-8.1, webbrowser-control

I have been trying to open a url(https://) in windows Webview control but it shows a blank white page in Webview.

In WebBrowser control it shows the page:

> We're having trouble with this site's security certificate

And it doesn't navigate to the url even  on clicking "Continue to Website(not recommended)"

What are some callbacks which can bypass the security error.

[image]

Comment: You need to install the certificate on the device to trust the domain. I don't think you can by-pass that screen on Windows Phone 8.1; maybe on Windows 10 with it's prompt callback.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I have tried with adding the certificate but its not working.